# Where is the unicode?

Tags: python, unicode

Using the Python module [unicode-nazi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicode-nazi) to detect unicode issues, I am running into this warning:

> /home/dotancohen/unicode-test.py:51: UnicodeWarning: Implicit conversion of unicode to str
>         print("Here is a phrase: " + str(phrase))

Since `phrase` is being *explicitly* cast to string, where is the implicit conversion? Surely `"Here is a phrase: "` is a string, as it is not preceded by `u`.

Comment: I don't know if that's what it complains about, but it sure wouldn't hurt to explicitly encode...

Comment: phrase.encode('1252')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to encode the `phrase` unicode value explicitly:

```
print("Here is a phrase: " + phrase.encode('some_codec'))
```

`str()` on a unicode value implicitly encodes that value, using the default codec (ASCII on Python 2).

Comment: I see! The warning message should probably say "Implicit encoding of unicode to some_codec in conversion to str". Thank you!